# Reading an image in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, path, bufferedimage

I have an image file in my project. The hierarchy looks like this:

[image: Project hierarchy]

I'm trying to read Manling.png into Manling.java using this code:

```
public BufferedImage sprite;

public Manling()
{
    try
    {
    File file = new File("resources/Manling.png");
    sprite = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    System.out.println(sprite.toString()); //This line is to test if it works
}
```

I always get a `NullPointerException` on the `println` statement, so I assume the path is wrong. I've tried moving the image to different places in the project and I've tried changing the file path (e.g. 'mine/resources/Manling.png' and '/resources/Manling.png'). Any ideas?

If you want a full compilable example, try this one:

```
package minesscce;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Mine extends JFrame
{
private BufferedImage sprite;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Mine mine = new Mine();
}

public Mine()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    try
    {
        File file = new File("resources/Manling.png");
        sprite = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    System.out.println(sprite.toString());
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.translate(getInsets().left, getInsets().top);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

}

Just set up the project like this, using any image you want:

[image: SSCCE]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
ImageIO.read(Mine.class.getResource("../minesscce.resources/Manling.png"));
```

---

Here's an example:

- **Hierarchy**

[image]

- **Result**

[image]

And here's the **code**...

```
public final class ImageResourceDemo {
    private static BufferedImage bi;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            loadImage();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();             
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void loadImage() throws IOException{
        bi = ImageIO.read(
                ImageResourceDemo.class.getResource("../resource/avatar6.jpeg"));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working when the image was in 'mine.resources' and the path was '../resources/Manling.png'. I don't really understand why, but I'm not going to complain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, root directory of your application is the project directory or the source directory. (Not sure exactly which one is)

If it is project directory then `resources/Manling.png` is `MineSSCCE/resources/Manling.png`. Nothing is there!

If it is the source directory, `resources/Manling.png` is `MineSSCCE/Source/resources/Manling.png`. Nothing is there either!

The actual location is `MineSSCCE/Source/minesscce/resources/Manling.png`
That is why it was not working.