# Java bufferedimage not loading

Tags: java, loading, bufferedimage

I have this image that I want to load but it always gives me an input= null exception.
This is the first bit of code:

```
Entity e = new Entity("images/meganium.png");
```

Here is the part that loads the image:

```
image = null;
    try{
        path = this.getClass().getResource(fileName);
        System.out.println(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(path);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Dun goofed in " + "SPrites");
    }
```

The structure is like this:

```
com/blah/bleh/Main
com/blah/bleh/images
com/blah/bleh/foo/bar/Loader Class
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1362)
at net.ofn.nyc.javagentleman.src.graphic.Sprite.<init>(Sprite.java:31)
at net.ofn.nyc.javagentleman.src.ent.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:21)
at net.ofn.nyc.javagentleman.JavaGentleman.<init>(JavaGentleman.java:27null)
at net.ofn.nyc.javagentleman.JavaGentleman.main(JavaGentleman.java:23)
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014123/reading-an-image-in-netbeans/

Comment: Instead of swallowing the IOException, print it out to see what's wrong: `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: show us the stack trace of your null exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a relative path for the image resource. With [Class.getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), relative paths are resolved against the package containing the class, so if the class loading the images is in package com.blah.bleh.foo.bar, then it will be looking for the image at /com/blah/bleh/foo/bar/images/meganium.png. getResource() returns null if it can't find the given resource and hence your IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand. How can I code it so it will work from other packages? Is passing a URL from the a package near the images folder the only way for it to work?

Comment: Just give getResource() an absolute path like "/com/blah/bleh/images/meganium.png". Note the leading '/'.

Comment: Weird, it still returns null. I dug up some older test apps that I had written and they seem to work fine. In fact in one of them it was able to load using "images/image.png" from a package next to the images package(foo/bar/images and foo/bar/classes in case I was confusing). I am completely confused. I did some more testing including putting the image in the same folder as the class and it still returned null.

Comment: I was fumbling through netbeans and noticed it wasnt running jdk7 so I changed the conf file and now my images load correctly! However my text in netbeans got messed up but one battle at a time I say.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have 2 separate directories, one named `images` the other named `Images` (capital 'I')?  Keep it consistent.  Your file system may not distinguish between the two, but Java does.

Comment: So is it `images` or `Images`?  Please edit your question.  BTW - the question you answered, was *not* what I asked.