# Problem using image from other local package

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a JLabel in the frame which I want to have different images when clicked upon different buttons. Achieving this was easy. Here is the code

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon (img);
    icon.getImage().flush();
    shopBanner.setIcon(icon);
```

The problem i0,s earlier I was providing full path to the image like C:\Documents\xxx.
Now when I tried the jar in some other computer I noticed the images are not used, that was obvious as the path assigned doesn't exist in other computer.

Back at project I have 2 packages, one for images called images and other for source files called smartshopping. I tried using couple of code but was not able to call the image from the package "images". Please help me fixing the problem. The project works fine in "my" computer if I provide full path as C:/Docs....

Here is the code

```
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/bb-banner-main.jpg"));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon (img);
    icon.getImage().flush();
    shopBanner.setIcon(icon);
```

I even tried

```
    URL img= this.getClass().getResource("images/icon.png");
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
    //icon.getImage().flush();
    shopBanner.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

Nothing working as of now. What am I doing wrong. Package of image is named images.

Comment: pretty answered by @mre in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014123/reading-an-image-in-netbeans/7014177#7014177

Comment: I tried searching before but couldn't find the reply you posted. Will check :)

Comment: I tried using .. (parent directory to current directory ) before but not worked. Will check again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Foo.class.getResource("images/icon.png")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) considers `images/icon.png` to be a relative path to the `Foo.class`. So if `Foo` is in package `com.bar`, it will look for `com/bar/images/icon.png`.

Put a slash at the beginning of the path to make it absolute (i.e. start at the root of the classpath).

BTW, you're making it unnecessarily complex. No need to read the image using ImageIO or to flush the image. Just do

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Foo.class.getResource("/images/icon.png"));
```

Note: I prefer hardcoding Foo.class rather than using `getClass()`, because `getClass()` will return another class if it's called by a subclass, and the relative path will thus point to another location which, most of the time, is not what is desired.

Comment: @JB Thanks man for such a nice explanation. But this thing is not working with Image class. I want the logo to store the icon for the application.

The setIconImage() depends on Image but not on ImageIcon.

 `logo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/images/icon.png");`

Comment: You really need to learn to read the javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). 1.ImageIcon.getImage() returns an Image object. 2. Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage() takes a file name as argument, not a resource path. There is an overloaded getImage() method which takes a URL as argument, though, and an URL is what is returned by Class.getResource().

Comment: Thanks man :) I do read the docs but not that extensively :)

Thanks to you guys my project is complete . Just need to polish it more.