# Reading Assets in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, resources, load

I am developing a little game where I use some pictures for the sprites etc etc. 
It works just fine when I load it from the disc like this

```
Image image = new Image("C:\\AppleMan.png");
```

but how can I load it from a foloder within the project. I am using eclipse as IDE and the language is Java :)

I took a screenshot of a sample project so you can see how I have importet the picture

[image: Le Image]

So I want to load the picture from that resource folder like this pseudo code

```
Image image = getResource("Resources/AppleMan.png");
```

but that simply doesn't work.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014123/reading-an-image-in-netbeans/7014177#7014177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should add Resources folder to classpath

2) You should locate file absolutely, i.e. "/Resources/AppleMan.png"

**P.S.**

3) Sorry, also note that getResource returns URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String

Comment: Please link the most current javadoc.

Answer (score -3):

You're passing a relative path when you were passing a absolute path before. Add the path of the Eclipse workspace.

For example, if your workspace is at C:\Workspace, you need to put

```
Image image = getResource("C:\\Workspace\\HowToGetResources\\Resources\\AppleMan.png");
```

Comment: having an absolute path referring a resource is horrible: and the OP is asking about loading from a resource folder